# How to change the ip range used for an IPCOP network interface

Tags: linux-networking, ipcop

I am using IPCOP v2.1

I currently have a blue network with the range 192.168.0.0/23.

I would like to change it to use 192.168.200.0/23.

Is there a way to simply make the change, or am I required to reinstall and reconfigure from scratch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the shell, you can just run setup and change the ip range for the blue adapter.

The options you do are:  Networking -> Address Settings -> Blue

Change the IP address to the desired setting and make sure that the subnet is correct to make the network the correct size.  Given you have it working with a /23 you don't need to change the subnet.